# python csv iteration; printing row 1 and 2, then 2 and 3 and so on

Tags: python, csv

I have been struggling with this for hours. I want to print line 2 and line 3, make a new line, and print line 3 and 4 + newline, next line 4 and 5 +\n ... actually the whole script does more things, but this is the key step I am struggling with.

This is my csv file

```
ids,CLSZ_0.7,CLID_0.7
ZINC04474603,48,45
ZINC12496548,48,45
ZINC12495776,48,45
ZINC04546442,48,45
ZINC28631806,48,45
```

this is my code

```
ifile = 'bin_503_07.csv'

with open(ifile, 'rb') as f:
    object = csv.reader(f)
    object.next()  #skips first line
    for row in object:
        next_row = object.next()
        print row
        print next_row
        print "\n"
```

this is what I get as a result (basically the original .csv but with a newline inserted between 2 rows). Instead I need that every new pair of lines begins with the second row from previous pair.

```
['ZINC04474603', '48', '45']
['ZINC12496548', '48', '45']


['ZINC12495776', '48', '45']
['ZINC04546442', '48', '45']


['ZINC28631806', '48', '45']
['ZINC08860448', '48', '45']


['ZINC04655414', '48', '45']
['ZINC08860490', '48', '45']
```

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't call your variable `object`, since it is a reserved word in Python. Call it some other name.

Comment: thanks for good point, I will definitely remember it for next time. However this doesn't solve my problem, it still doesn't work

Comment: @Pocin: comments here aren't for providing answers which solve your problem, they're for, well, *comments*.  If heltonbiker's comment was intended to solve your problem he'd have posted it as an answer. :-)

Comment: @DSM lesson learned, I am smarter every day. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
ifile = 'bin_503_07.csv'

with open(ifile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    reader.next()  #skips first line
    previous_row = reader.next()  # load first actual line
    for row in reader:   # this already calls "next()"
        print previous_row
        print row
        print   # no need to print "\n", empty "print" already does that
        previous_row = row  # "advance" by replacing previous with current
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    a,b = tee(infile)
    next(b,None)
    for line1, line2 in zip(a,b):
        print line1.rstrip('\n')
        print line2.rstrip('\n')
        print ''
```